# Is there any library that gathers marine species vocalizations?

Tags: machine-learning, identification, marine-species, dataset

I would like to automatize the analysis of marine soundscapes by training a neural network that can detect and identify marine species. However, I need a large amount of training data to build such model.

I have searched for collections / libraries of marine species' vocalization or noise (something similar to [xeno canto](https://xeno-canto.org/) but for marine species) but I did not found anything that I can use. For instance [this paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fevo.2022.810156/full) describes the need of gathering existing libraries but the idea hasn't been concertize yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 18):

There are some resources available, but often hampered by the sheer size of these acoustic datasets which makes it difficult to keep them online. http://www.mobysound.org/ has some examples. Also check out the datasets from the DCLDE workshop series. A link to the latest of these is https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/ore/dclde/. From there you can follow links to previous meetings. Each workshop provided an annotated dataset for download.

Answer (score 17):

For fish sounds, there is also a relatively new and growing site, [https://fishsounds.net](https://fishsounds.net/index.js), which hosts some downloadable recordings along with spectrograms, and citations for where they were described. For some species, links to other libraries are given.

Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 15):

Nothing as comprehensive as xenocanto for the marine realm. At Fishbase https://www.fishbase.se/search.php, you can filter for sound files ("Information by Topic"), and there's a pretty decent list of results. The Watkins Marine Mammal Sound Database has a collection as well: https://cis.whoi.edu/science/B/whalesounds/index.cfm. At the Macaulay Library https://www.macaulaylibrary.org/ you can filter by sounds, but you have to request files from them directly and my students have had varied success in response to their requests.

Answer (score 14):

Dosits' library might also be of help. Here's the link to their audio gallery https://dosits.org/galleries/audio-gallery/

All the best of luck, sounds like a great project!

Answer (score 11):

Cornell University's [Macaulay Library](https://www.macaulaylibrary.org/) has a very comprehensive and curated collection of avain and marine mammal sounds. They are also rated by quality if you want to test your neural network. However, you need to submit an official request to gain access to the sound files, and they are pretty strict on the sounds being used for educational or testing purposes.

For a large collection of marine soundscapes in different environments, [DOSITS](https://dosits.org) is a great place to start.

Comment: Hi @etgriffiths. I've edited the hyperlinks to follow Markdown syntax. However the Macaulay library link is not valid - please update/fix?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Apologies. I wrote the comment on my phone and the links didn't translate well. :P

Answer (score 8):

This site has a compilation of publicly available bioacoustic datasets & repo's (not necessarily specific to marine, but has some marine datasets included).
https://bioacousticsdatasets.weebly.com/index.html#datasets

There are also some listed on LILA BC's acoustics page here: https://lila.science/otherdatasets#bioacoustics