# Library of odontocete vocalisation properties/characteristics

Tags: echolocation, cetacean, sound-library

I'm looking at echolocation clicks of an odontocete species and want to compare the properties/characteristics of the clicks to other odontocete species. I'm aware of sound libraries such as [DOSITS](https://dosits.org/) but this mostly provides sound clips with spectrograms and a brief description. I'm mainly looking for things like click spectrums (on and off axis) and waveforms. I have found some in papers on detection and classification but these are usually limited to two co-occurring species or multiple species found in one region. Is there a review paper or website that hosts this information for a larger number of species?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A large database of sounds from different locations is something that the marine bioacoustics community is sorely lacking unfortunately - there have been various attempts but the complexity and size of acoustic data has hindered progress. As the field expands and we require more automated analysis methods (usually requiring training data), publicly available, well annotated datasets are going to become increasingly important.

As a side note, the first step to making a large database of sounds is a good metadata system for acoustics. [Tethys](https://tethys.sdsu.edu/) is a good system but complex to use - we are hoping to make PAMGuard's metadata system compatible with Tethys and hopefully other software will follow suit. That would make uploading datasets far easier and hopefully provide a basis for a more comprehensive community driven data repository.

Comment: good to hear you will use Tethys in PamGuard. I also decided to use Tethys.

Answer (score 3):

The datasets from the Detection, Classification, and Density Estimation (DCLDE) Workshops contain what I consider the best annotated sets of marine mammal sounds, but they are large, and you'd likely have to spend quite a bit of time digging through to find exactly what you are looking for and then make those spectrograms for comparison yourself.

The answer on this related question has where to find them: https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/a/8/42

Answer (score 2):

While a comprehensive global database is lacking as mentioned by Jamie, there are a few good peer reviewed publications you can glean information from! [Christine Erbe's 2017 review of marine mammals](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40857-017-0101-z) in Australian waters has some echolocation click information,  [Simone Baumann-Pickering](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1121/1.4817832?casa_token=7D-80SC0HdEAAAAA%3AhSCH-kikc8PctYOclcAWUI1O8J1faRcboh03b9Y_E-USQgAborZGUWloC9s4YPnSHvbnKVyowGNo) has a great summary of beaked whale echolocation clicks, then you can always search by species and compile. Of course more summative resources would be so valuable and hopefully will be made available eventually!